# Upload iPhone app for review without in-app purchase

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have completed my iPhone app. It is an app in the finance category. Now, I wish to incorporate in-app purchase. 
But before this, I was thinking if I can get the app approved by Apple first.
I will limit 2 features in the app (which can be purchased via in-app purchase once it is added). 
I wish to make it live on app store first (with limited features). Then later, I can incorporate in-app purchases. Is it possible for me to do so? Because I will be limiting certain features of the app. Will Apple accept this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, there is an option when the App should hit the AppStore. I usually selected the current date as the desired AppStore date. But you could select some point in the future, say one year from now. That should solve your problem, doesn't it?

Until then, you'll see if Apple accepts your app and can later on upload new versions with additional features.

Comment: I wish to make the app live on App Store so that people start using it. I wish to see their feedback. Only after this, I want to incorporate in-app purchases. Will Apple accept an app with limited features?

Comment: That's okay. Upload it, check if Apple accepts it and upload an updated version later...

Answer (score 0):

Any minimum viable product(new features can be added in the future updates) can be uploaded to App store. Checkout the [Apple's Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#functionality)